# Can we create a table in a database without dbo permissions.?

Tags: sql-server

I have to create a table in one database where I have no dbo permission.

Can I do that?

Comment: It depends.  What permissions do you have?

Comment: I have read-only permissions. I heard that..I can have a stored procedure...and inside that I can create a table with "AS Dbo"

Comment: But if you have readonly permission, you don't have the ability to create (or probably run) the stored procedure (stored procedures require execute permissions).

Comment: I'm sorry. I do have execute permission.  But not write/alter permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a table as long as you are a member of the `db_owner` or `db_ddladmin` database roles, or if you are explicitly granted the `CREATE TABLE` permission.  Obviously, if you're in the `sysadmin` server role you can also create tables.

You can't necessarily read or modify data inside the table(s) you create, but you can create them.

These permissions are not defaults, so if you have not been granted any of these you're out of luck unless your dba will do so for you.